# Grails 3.2 with Angularjs1.5 List not returning all records

Tags: angularjs, grails

I don't know if this is a grails or angular issue although I suspect the former. Database has 200+ records but list is serving up exactly 100 instead. What am I missing here?

fybkbraEditController.js (Angular 1.5)

```
function FybkbraEditController(Fybkbra, $stateParams, $state, Fytrnlt, Fytbank, Stvnatn, $filter) {
var vm = this;
var max = 100000, offset = 0;

vm.fytrnltList = Fytrnlt.list({max: max, offset: offset});
vm.fytbankList = Fytbank.list({max: max, offset: offset});
vm.stvnatnListFilt = Stvnatn.list({max: max, offset: offset}); //200+ records in table but only exactly 100 records are loaded



vm.getCS = function () {


   vm.res01 = ($filter('filter')(vm.stvnatnListFilt, {stvnatncode: vm.fybkbra.fybkbranatncode.toString()}, true));
```

html code

```
 <div class="fieldcontain">
        <label for="country">Country *</label>
  <select ng-model="vm.fybkbra.fybkbranatncode"
            ng-options="stvnatn.stvnatncode as (stvnatn.id + ':' + stvnatn.stvnatnnation ) for stvnatn in vm.stvnatnList | orderBy:'stvnatnnation' | limitTo:500"
            ng-change="vm.getCS()"
            ng-required="true"
            id="country">

    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Your controller uses some max(params.max, 100) logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your controller code (or whatever the controller is invoking to get the records) but because the number of records being returned is an even 100, my guess that your code is doing something like `SomeDomainClass.list(max: 100)` (which is what the default `RestfulController` class does... not sure if you are using that).

Comment: Note that if you set a `max` request parameter, it may or may not be respected depending on what your server code is doing.  A common thing is to put a guard in place to keep a user from specifying `max` as a query string parameter to cause problems in your app by asking it to load a giant number of records.  That often looks like `params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)`.  Which will prevent the `max` that is used in the query from ever being greater than 100.